# Are physical probabilities also quantized?

Tags: energy, quantum-information, probability, discrete

In physics there is quanta and energy occurs per this unit. Is it it then reasonable that probability also is quantized since energy is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) is a statistical measure used widely in predicting both classical and quantum mechanical behavior. It is not a variable entering the differential equations either classically or quantum mechanically.

In quantum mechanics variables turn into [operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_%28physics%29#Operators_in_quantum_mechanics) which then enter differential equations and show, depending on the boundary conditions on the solutions, a quantized behavior of the variable that the operator describes, for example "energy." Now the square of the wavefunction, which describes the state of the system as a function of energy,  gives the probability of finding the system with that energy. If the boundary conditions are such that the energy values are quantized it means that the probability will be high (near 1) for the quantized states for specific energy and low to zero at the rest.

Probability always goes from 0 to 1. If one is scanning probability versus energy against an  energy quantized spectrum,  it will be a saw tooth plot with maxima close to 1  and minima close to 0. Measurements confirm this:

Look  at this spectrum  plot of an intensity versus energy.

[image: spectrum]

If each line is turned into a probabity plot by normalizing the number of photons making it up  to one, there will be a width, but the saw tooth pattern is evident.

So no, probability is not a variable and cannot be quantized.

Comment: While on the one hand, I do not wish to bump a very old post. It is notw 6ish years since and I wonder if you, who somehow understood this question that I think is "deep", have had further insights since then. 

The part I'd like to challenge is " If one is scanning probability versus energy against an energy quantized spectrum, it will be a saw tooth plot with maxima close to 1 and minima close to 0. Measurements confirm this." Do they really? Has this been measured very very precisely. If so, I'd really like to read about that experiment.

Comment: @h  Look at this emission plot http://lh4.ggpht.com/_vHwtYfzMc9c/Stqve77265I/AAAAAAAAAWM/IK-nvpCWM3s/s1600-h/Slide2%5B6%5D.jpg . The quantized energy levels are saw tooth like. On the left it is intensity. Each line can turn into a probability plot by normalizing the number of photons to 1. At the center of the line probability is the maximum, so I should have said, maximum (the integral of the curve is one) and not one, but I do not want to edit and push the answer to the first page.

Answer (score -1):

I've not read about evidence for this, but it seems it must be true.  For example, when measuring electron spin, how could there be a true *continuum* of test angles for the static magnetic field?  Since the magnetic field itself is quantized, and there are always thermal perturbations, etc., the test field angle always has some uncertainty in it (as does the nearly zero angle of the field used to prepare the electrons).  Thus, there is always a resolution limit, which is effectively a quantization.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).