# Can Probability be quantized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, wavefunction, probability, discrete

There are conjectures that quantities like space, time, energy, etc. are quantized and can only get some discrete values. I was wondering if there is any relationship in physics that interrelates physical probabilities to these quantities, such that there will also be a quanta for probability, or probability is always continuous in the range of (0,1).

There is a very old article in this regrad which has only proposed that such a possibility is studied:

https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.64.376.2

Comment: I read Phys Rev "article" that you linked to. First of all, it's not an article but merely a letter to the editor. Secondly, the letter writer doesn't provide any physical evidence or motivation for why a theory of quantized probability should be considered. He merely points out that it would eliminate the "inherent aversion" to the conclusion of the "lots-of-monkeys-at-typewriters" example. Don't see why physicists should seriously consider a theory which doesn't seem to serve any purpose at explaining anything.

Comment: The writer mentions that there might be interrelations between his "quanta of probability" and quantas of time or energy. I think he hasn't been a physicist, but I would like to know if there is any relationship between "probability" and energy or time, such that quantization of these quantities leads to th quantization of probability?

Comment: Looks to be a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47908/25301 ?